# Deserializing XML with nested fields to a single JavaObject

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson, jaxb

My goal is to convert the XML to JavaObject and have the JavaObject be able to handle one or more "Tasks".

I would also like to be able to convert the JavaObject to JSON as well.

How can this be done? At it's current state, I am able to convert if only one task exists, anymore results in an error.

I have an XML file that follows this structure:

```
<Plan>
    <ID></ID>
    <Comment></Comment>
    <CreateTime></CreateTime>
    <Task>...</Task>
    <Task>...</Task>
    <Task>...</Task>
</Plan>
```

Each Task element is structured like so:

```
    <Task>
      <Type></Type>
      <Time></Time>
      <Target>
         <Code></Code>
         <TargetId></TargetId>
         <Content>
            <Stuff1></Stuff1>
            <Stuff2></Stuff2>
            <Stuff3></Stuff3>
         </Content>
      </Target>
    </Task>
```

I am able to deserialize the XML when there is only one Task involved. Anymore gives me errors.

**My Classes (simplified) are as follows:**

```
@Root(name = "Plan")
public class Plan{
   @Element(name = "ID")
   private String id;
   
   @Element(name = "Comment")
   private String comment;

   @Element(name = "CreateTime")
   private String createTime;

   @Element(name = "Task")
   private Task task; 
}

@Root(name = "Task")
public class Task{

   @Element(name = "Type")
   private String type;
   
   @Element(name = "Time")
   private String time;

   @Element(name = "Target")
   private Target target;
}

@Root(name = "Target")
public class Target{

   @Element(name = "Code")
   private String code;
   
   @Element(name = "TargetId")
   private String targetId;

   @Element(name = "Content")
   private Content content;
}

@Root(name = "Content")
public class Content{

   @Element(name = "Stuff1")
   private String stuff1;
   
   @Element(name = "Stuff2")
   private String stuff2;

   @Element(name = "Stuff3")
   private String stuff3;
}
```

In the schema file, I set this but doesn't seem to work:

```
<xs:element name="Task" type="Task" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
```

Answer (score 1):

> At it's current state, I am able to convert if only one task exists,
> anymore results in an error.

This happens because your element annotation interprets the *task* tag as a property, so if there is more than one it raises an error. To avoid this behaviour you can use the [`JacksonXmlElementWrapper`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlElementWrapper.html) annotation you can apply to your *task* list:

```
public class Plan {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Task")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    List<Task> tasks;
}

public class Task {}
```

This above is a starting basic example you can use to define more complicated xmls.

Comment: @Gamblers You have to create a Target class and put inside the Task class the Target field with @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Target"), after you begin to put inside the Target class the other fields and so on.